# Direct comparison test yielded different result from alternating series test for the same series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine the converge and divergence of the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos{n\pi}}{n^{3/4}}$$

I thought that I could do a direct comparison test, and could compare it with this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{n^{3/4}}$$

And it is a divergent p-series since $\frac{3}{4} < 1$.

Next, I thought I could show that this p-series will always be smaller than the first series, which would mean I can conclude that the first series is divergent.

$\cos{n\pi} \geq -1$

$\frac{\cos{n\pi}}{n^{3/4}} \geq \frac{-1}{n^{3/4}}$ for all $ n > 0 $

However, the answer key for this problem converted the series into an alternating one, because the cosine part oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. It then went on to show that it converges. I see that pattern now, however, I don't understand why my method gave me the wrong answer. Is there anything that I'm missing in the way that I did it?

Comment: Can you use comparison test on a sequence which is not always the same sign?

Comment: Comparison test is only valid for series with non-negative terms.

Comment: As alluded to in the other comments, this approach won't work for your series that oscillates as you are getting cancellations in that sum that aren't taking place in the sum which you are comparing it to...

Comment: It's worth remembering which convergence test (singular) works for series that have nonconstant signs (in fact, requires alternating signs) and all the other tests that address absolute convergence (so require constant signs).

Comment: A general and powerful way to deal with this type of series is Abel's transformation (summation by parts).